# Resource created conditionally based on variable, how to ignore changes to this variable and prevent from resource deletion

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I have terraform module where i am creating two resources based on same condition:

```hcl
length(keys(var.service_name)) > 0
```

```hcl
resource "mapping" "qsm"{
for_each = { for key, value in var.service_name : key=> value if length(keys(var.service_name)) > 0 }
    region = each.key
    service_name = each.value.name
    name = "test-qsm"
}

resource "profile" "bcp" {
  for_each = { for k, v in coalesce(merge([for profile in var.sp : profile.pc if length(keys(var.service_name)) > 0]...), {}) : k => v }
name="bg"
}

variable "service_name" {
  description = "The name of the service"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {}
}
```

This value of variable service_name is provided from terragrunt.hcl. When i remove this variable in terragrunt.hcl both resources are getting deleted. But i want to just delete resource mapping not profile resources. The resource profile should be deleted when i call `terragrunt destroy`. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What happens if you comment out just the first block of code then?

Comment: @MarkoE That doesn't work as resource mapping when created creates some resource say X internally which not managed by terraform and the resource profile is dependent on this resource X.

Comment: "But i want to just delete resource mapping" Please elaborate on what you mean by this statement.

Comment: "But i want to just delete resource mapping" means since the resource is created based on var.service_name when i remove this variable from terragrunt.hcl it will be empty map and hence mapping resource gets deleted here. but resource profile is also getting deleted. I want to retain profile resource in this scenario.